# Get a count of all employees who belong to USA using VBA Macro

Tags: excel, vba

Consider a table with 100 employees belonging to USA, Canada, England, Denmark, etc. Need to get a VBA Macro to get a count of all employees who belong to USA, Canada, England, Denmark and so on.

I can get it done through the formula using CountIfs but not through the VBA Macro.

Comment: You can also use that formula in vba code as `count = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(...)`.

Comment: Am actually new to VBA Macro. Can you please help me write the code completely. Below is the table:

Country Employee
USA a
USA b
USA c
USA d
USA e
USA f
Canada g
Canada h
Canada i
Canada a
Canada b
Canada c
Canada d
England e
England f
England g
England h
England i
England a
England b

Comment: Show me your excel formula.

Comment: =COUNTIFS(Sheet2!B3:B23,"USA",Sheet2!H3:H23,"A")

Comment: The above formula will return the count of A for USA. So if there are 5 A's which belongs to USA then the new table will consists the country as USA and the count as 5.

Comment: Why VBA? This can be done with a pivot table or with worksheet functions. Please explain the need for code.

Answer (score 1):

Here, my approach for you. Try with this.

```
Sheet2.Range("C5") = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Sheet2.Range("B3:B23"), "USA", Sheet2.Range("H3:H23"), "A")
```

Comment: Instead of a msg box, can the count be saved in another cell?

Comment: Yes, you can. I also modified my answer.

Comment: I get a invalid or unqualified reference error message. :(

Comment: rachanmarshall@hotmail.com is my email address. Can I email the excel workbook to you so that you can check what am trying to achieve? If yes, then please email me so that I can send you the excel file.

Comment: Share a sample file on a file sharing service like Dropbox or OneDrive. Don't take details off-line. This is a public site, and all components of discussions should be public, too. Use a sample file with dummy data, but with the same structure as your original file. Replace real names with dummy names. Upload that for all to see.

Comment: No, edit your post by adding your code. Okay..! So, we can check cause of error.

Answer (score 0):

13 post and I don't understand wath you what, I don't answered at why VBA, why not excel formula o pivot
You can usa a simply formula where you want, with explicit criteria or dynamically also
[image]

Comment: Well the country and the employee can increase and am looking to look until the value is empty and if found in future the vba should add the same in the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
    Sub Test()
Dim Masterworksht As Worksheet
Dim Oworksht As Worksheet
Dim intRow, intMRow, intH, intNor, intL, intClosed As Integer

Set Masterworksht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Master")
Set Oworksht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output")
intRow = 4

Do
    intH = 0
    intNor = 0
    intL = 0
    intClosed = 0
    intMRow = 3
    Do
        If (Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 1).Value = Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 2).Value) Then
            If (Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 8).Value = "High") Then
                intH = intH + 1
            ElseIf (Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 8).Value = "Low") Then
                intL = intL + 1
            ElseIf (Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 8).Value = "Normal") Then
                intNor = intNor + 1
            End If
            If (Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 12).Value = "Closed") Then
                intClosed = intClosed + 1
            End If
        End If
        intMRow = intMRow + 1
    Loop While Masterworksht.Cells(intMRow, 1).Value <> ""
    Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 2).Value = intH
    Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 3).Value = intNor
    Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 4).Value = intL
    Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 6).Value = intClosed
    intRow = intRow + 1
Loop While Oworksht.Cells(intRow, 1).Value <> ""

End Sub
```

Comment: But the problem is that it works when I have in 2 different sheets but not in the same worksheet

Comment: This looks like a continuation of the question rather than an answer.